# Postgresql dynamic call with out-parameter

Tags: postgresql

I try to development a dynamic call, but could not manage to handle out-paramter

```
drop schema test cascade;
create schema test;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test.Test(p_in IN TEXT, p_out OUT TEXT) AS
$body$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '-->  %', p_in;
    p_out := p_in;
    RAISE NOTICE '-->  %', p_out;
END;
$body$
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test.Callout(p_routine IN TEXT, p_in IN TEXT, p_out OUT TEXT) AS
$body$
DECLARE
v_stmt TEXT;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '->  %', p_in;
    EXECUTE 'CALL ' || p_routine || ' ($1, $2)' USING p_in, p_out;
    RAISE NOTICE '->  %', p_out;
END;
$body$
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;

DO
$body$
DECLARE
    x    TEXT;
    y    TEXT;
BEGIN
    x := 'HALLO';
    --
    CALL test.Callout(p_routine => 'test.TEST', p_in => x, p_out => y);
    --
    RAISE NOTICE '> %', y;
END;
$body$
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;
```

The Value is assigned in test.TEST, but not passed back to the test.Callout.
How can I get the value p_out back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `EXECUTE 'CALL ' || p_routine || ' ($1, $2)' USING p_in, p_out` does not place the result automatically back into any variable, even if there are `OUT` parameters defined for the command enveloped in the `EXECUTE` command. In other words, `EXECUTE` does not dynamically evaluate the full procedure signature in the way that the interpreter does otherwise. The solution is to explicitly tell `EXECUTE` where to store any results from the call:

```
EXECUTE 'CALL ' || p_routine || ' ($1, $2)' INTO p_out USING p_in, p_out;
```